# web crawler which retrieves website source code

Tags: web-crawler

I want to make something a bit difficult.I want to make a crawler which except from the links will download also the source code of the site.And after this,i want to make a program which will search the source code of each site if a statement exists(for example if there is a heading exclude this site).

Comment: this is not possible at all unless you mean the *source HTML*

Comment: your question is not very specific, and has already been answered for most common languages on this site. please use the search feature keeping in mind that all web crawlers retrieve the pages' "source code" (html) at some point. that is the only thing to be retreived.

Answer (score 2):

I once found a PHP script for something similar, but of course it grabs the client-side code (as SpyrosP accurately said). See http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4616-PHP-Crawl-Web-pages-to-search-for-given-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# sample for using HttpWebRequest object for getting the information.

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read server code from a script. You can only grab HTML or whatever else runs on client (i.e. javascript).

Comment: there is no "if" in html :) Grabbing html though is what every crawler does and it's very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through **jsoup** 
jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML.
[jsoup - official site link](http://jsoup.org)
You can retrieve the information, Parse Html by using tags.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test with the linux comando wget?
http://m.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

I think that you could test too.